# Why is my window loaded each time I access `self.window`

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I've used this code to configure a window. It has worked before.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"self = %p", self);
    [(NSPanel *)self.window setWorksWhenModal: NO];
}
```

Anyway, each time I access `self.window` the window is loaded from the nib. This is a problem here because it makes this recursive. but it's a problem on other places as well since I will get a different window each time!

[image]

From "NSWindowController":

```
    /* The window getter will load the nib file (if there is one and it has not yet been loaded) and then return the window. 
If it has to load the window, it will first call -windowWillLoad, then -loadWindow,  then -windowDidLoad.  
To affect nib loading or do something before or after it happens, you should always override those other methods.

        The window setter is used internally from -initWithWindow: or when a controller's nib file is loaded (as the "window" outlet gets connected).
You can also call it yourself if you want to create the window for a window controller lazily, but you aren't loading it from a nib.
This can also be used to set the window to nil for cases where your subclass might not want to keep the window it loaded from a nib, but rather only wants the contents of the window.
Setting the window to nil, after the nib has been loaded, does not reset the -isWindowLoaded state. 
A window controller will only load its nib file once.  This method makes sure the window does not release when closed, and it sets the controller's -windowFrameAutosaveName onto the window and updates the window's dirty state to match the controller's document (if any). 
It also calls -setWindowController: on the window.  You can override this if you need to know when the window gets set, but call super.
    */
    @property (nullable, strong) NSWindow *window;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What objects are in your window NIB? I suspect you have created an instance of your window controller class in the NIB.

So any time you load that NIB (perhaps via an instance of your window controller class that you create in code), a new instance of your window controller is created. That new instance receives `-awakeFromNib` and requests its `window`, which causes it to load another instance of the NIB, and repeats the process.

A window controller should not be instantiated in a window NIB. The File's Owner placeholder in the NIB should be configured to have the class of the window controller. The window controller should be instantiated in code and initialized such that it uses itself as the owner of the NIB. That will make it so it fills the place that File's Owner is holding for it.

Also, you should probably avoid overrides of `-awakeFromNib`. It can be called unexpectedly. It's generally safer to override `-windowDidLoad` for those sorts of tasks.

Comment: Oh, that was exactly it. I had the controller object in the window NIB! Thank you!

Comment: Or wait, let me verify this again.. Just recreated it, and now no objects in NIB, but still get it, ill get back.

Comment: I actually still had the problem. But I was still accessing `self.window` from awakeFromNib, but seems to work good now that I removed that as well